# What’s the easiest way to install a mason package?

Tags: installation, chapel, mason

I want to install a mason package but I couldn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I talked to programmer who writes mason package manager, he said that installing a mason package look like:

```
mason new MyPkg
cd MyPkg
mason add csm@0.1.0
# MyPkg.chpl can now `use csm`
mason build
```